# Select multiple images within a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a gallery page in my application. I have a requirement where I need to create a new album by selecting some of the images on a page. I am displaying them in a div as shown below. Each image in the page has been given a unique id.

[image]

I want to allow users to select some of the images in that div to create a new album. Selected images should be indicated by a special styling, similar to the image below. How can I detect when a user has selected an image, and display the selected images accordingly?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/9z3gL/)

Given a set of images in a `<div>`, your image suggests you want to add some special styling to them after a certain user event (presumably a click) which represents a user selection. You can accomplish this with jQuery and CSS by binding a click handler to each image, and applying a certain CSS style when they are selected.

Then, when the user clicks 'Create Album', you can find all of the images which are currently selected and display only those when showing your album.

Obviously the 'Create Album' action in your case will likely involve some kind of POST action which submits the list of selected images to your server. For a client-side example, however, see my jsFiddle demo above. The relevant part of that JavaScript/CSS is shown below. Since I don't know what your DOM looks like, you may have to adjust some of these CSS/jQuery selectors to match your page.

Style selected images differently with CSS:

```
img {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
img.selected {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Toggle `selected` class with jQuery (assuming images are in a `<div>` with id "gallery"):

```
$("#gallery > img").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Get list of selected images with jQuery:

```
$("img.selected");
```